# tf.signal.overlap_and_add throws Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When i run the following snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input, layers

segments = 1
segment_length = 64000
inputs = Input(shape=(segments, segment_length))
net = tf.reshape(inputs, (-1, 1, segment_length * segments))
net = layers.Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=16, strides=8, use_bias=False, padding='same', data_format='channels_first')(net)
net = tf.reshape(net, (-1,2, 512, 8000))
net = tf.transpose(net, perm=[0,1,3,2])
net = layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(512,), use_bias=False)(net)
out = tf.signal.overlap_and_add(net, 8)
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    out = tf.signal.overlap_and_add(net, 8)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/signal/reconstruction_ops.py", line 116, in overlap_and_add
    paddings = array_ops.concat([outer_paddings, paddings], 0)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1598, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1189, in concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 414, in _apply_op_helper
    as_ref=input_arg.is_ref)
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1409, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor
    ctx=ctx))
  File "/home/mmoran/.miniconda3/envs/convtasnet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1307, in convert_to_tensor
    raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "
RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

I already try to wrap `tf.signal.overlap_and_add` in a `@tf.function` but i had the same results. In addition to that i also tried to disable the eager mode but when i did that the result of the `tf.signal.overlap_and_add` was `(None, 2, None)` breaking the my custom loss function which uses the shape for creating a mask.
What am i doing wrong? Is it a bug?

My system setup is:

```
Ubuntu 19.10
tf-nightly==2.2.0.dev20200218
tf-nightly-gpu==2.2.0.dev20200218
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really answering the question about tf.signal.overlap_and_add here but overlap add for ConvTasnet can be implemented using transposed convolution with one kernel, a kernel size of 16 and a stride of 8. And it'll probably be more efficient as well.